# angular automatically removes parameters form url

Tags: angularjs, parameters, routes

In my application i am passing parameters for controller and read it using javascript as below.

**localhost:8080/app/conroller#parameter=value**

now problem is if i open my conroller in url and than append #parameter=value than only it works.

but i want to put whole link in anchor tag.
and when i click outside application than it automatically reroute **localhost:8080/app/conroller** and don't accept parameters.Although when opening that url if i apped #parameter=value* part than it works perfect.

i am using html5mode = true.
i search lots of document but didnt find right solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if I get what you are asking but I think this is what you are getting at:

```
href="/app/conroller#parameter=value" target="_self"
```

Try adding the target self.

If that doesn't work you could try setting a base url `<base href="/"></base>`

You could try using `?` for the query parameter instead of the `#`

Comment: No it is not working. Angular automatically reroute it to app/controller.

Comment: Can you post your route configuration?

Comment: app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
   templateUrl: 'home.html',
   controller: 'homeController',
                        title:"Home"

  })
  .when('/controller', {
   templateUrl: 'controller.html',
   controller: 'controller',
                        title:"controller"
  })
  .otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/view1'
  });
$locationProvider.html5mode(true);
}]);

Comment: i found that localhost:8080/app#/conroller#parameter=value works perfectly from anchor tag but is there any other way to remove # before controller in anchor tag.

Comment: Try setting: `<base href="/app"></base>` and then in your anchor `href="/controller#parameter=value"`

Comment: I just noticed you have a typo: `conroller` in the code you have given, maybe just double check this is not in your markup as well.

Comment: I am using anchor tag outside of application and app is on different server so I am not able to use href="controller..." and for typo controller is only example I am using different name in app.